# How to download any movie with qBittorrent?

Tags: qbittorrent

I recently downloaded the qBittorrent, but when I want to download a movie, and asking
for choose an application, I just can't find the way to do it... Any ideas?

Comment: You are downloading the movie via torrent, right?

Comment: As a side note, have you verified that the qBittorent application is actually installed and works by clicking on it in the Applications Dash ?

Comment: It was present on the Launcher on the left side, I have an 12.04 by the way...

Answer (score 2):

when you have installed it i.e qbittorrent in your Ubuntu you will have an option for that in the context menu. you can get it by rightclick at that torrent downloaded link. [image]

If its not found in the Context menu then from the context menu choose other application option then you will have window opened . From that window click at `file system` and choose `usr` then select `bin` and in that `qbittorrent`.

Then afterwards torrents will open with qbittorrent.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I supposed to answer... I actually trying to download a movie, but when I need to choose an application, the qBittorrent is not present... For the uTorrent it started automatically...

Comment: yes If you double click it then default application will choose that. you see the second option in the context menu open with other application from there you can choose .

Comment: Now, finally got it... Thanks, learned something today  too...:)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the preferences in your Internet Browser, I am assuming that you are using Mozilla Firefox.

Go to the preferences.( File -> Edit -> Preferences) and navigate to the 'Applications Tab'.

For BitTorrent Seed File, select 'Qbittorent'

Now when you open the torrent, qbittorent should open.

If you have any problem please let us know.

Comment: Thanks. I went there, but I couldn't find that Bit Torrent Seed File.. Anywhere else?

Comment: Then you could double click on the torrent file, and when it asks to choose an applicaion, if qBittorent is present, click on it.. If its not present click on browse and the directory /usr/bin (as described in the above answer) and here qbittorent should be present, click on it.